# AND operator in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql

While debugging some code, I stumbled into an error pretty much like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE family_size > 3
ORDER BY birthday AND registered=0;
```

The error is that the AND clause was *intended* to be in the WHERE clause. Ie:

```
WHERE family_size > 3 AND registered=0
```

The "flawed" query throws no SQL syntax error or warning.
So I assume it's valid SQL. (right?)

But more interestingly, what is it supposed to do?
I tested this is a couple of RDBMS and my best bet is that it's doing something like:

```
ORDER BY (birthday AND registered=0);
```

Am I right?

Is this intended SQL behavior? (such as expected resolution of operator precedence)
Or is it some sort of fall-back?

---

Some details I should add after reading comments:

- The original query was for use in MySQL, but I'm mostly interested in the intended use of the SQL language.
- I did a quick test in MSAccess and behaved pretty much the same.
- The columns were originally integers, but for the MSAccess test I did, I used Date/Time for 'birthday', just because.

Comment: Are you running MySQL?

Comment: And what are the datatypes of the 2 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid SQL as long as both sub-expressions, `(birthday)` and `(registered=0`) are boolean expressions (or can be implicitly converted to). And while `registered = 0` is boolean, the `birthday` is probably not.

In MySQL though, integer expressions can be converted to boolean and vice versa, according to the rules: `FALSE` is `0`, `TRUE` is `1` (and anything other than `0` is `TRUE` for the integer->boolean conversion).

So, that's what happens, an implicit conversion. For any birthday value other than `0`, the expression is evaluated as:

```
(TRUE AND registered=0)
```

which is equivalent to just `(registered=0)`.

In Access, if I remember right, `-1` stands for `TRUE` (instead of 1), but anything other than 0 is also converted to true, so the observed behaviour would be the same.

The final use of the expression in the `ORDER BY` depends on how the DBMS sorts boolean values. I suppose that both (MySQL and Access) use `FALSE < TRUE`